# Admob integration for blackberry

Tags: blackberry, admob, ads-api

I am developing an application which requires Admob integration.I have googled much about it but could not find any help about it except for one question in blackberry forums and that too with no answers to it.

If anyone has been successful in integrating Admob with blackberry , then please help me also in doing this..

Thanx

Comment: Have you tried contacting AdMob directly?  Seems like it would be in their best interest to help you.

Comment: Thanx for the advice Marc.I will contact them..